# Tastypie, filtering many to many relationships

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have two models that are linked by another model through a many to many relationship.

Here's the models themselves

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=108, primary_key=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tags', through='PostTags')


class Tags(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=108, primary_key=True)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Posts', through='PostTags')

class PostTags(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=108, primary_key=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField()
    post_id = models.ForeignKey('Posts', db_column='post_field')
    tag_id = models.ForeignKey('Tags', db_column='tag_field')
```

And the tastypie resources

```
class PostsResource(ModelResource):
    tags = fields.ToManyField('django_app.api.TagsResource', 'tags', null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Posts.objects.filter(deleted=0)
        resource_name = 'posts'

class TagsResource(ModelResource):
    posts = fields.ToManyField('django_app.api.PostsResource', 'posts', null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Tags.objects.filter(deleted=0)
        resource_name = 'tags'
```

On the posttags table there is a deleted flag, is it possible to only return linked results when the deleted flag in PostTags is 0?

I have tried [this](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=ToMany#tomanyfield) filter attribute in tastypie but it only seems to care about the flag in the linked table(ie tags or posts) not the actual table doing the linking.

Comment: Have you tried `queryset = Posts.objects.filter(posttags__deleted=0)` in Meta for each Resource?

Comment: It's odd, that half works. As in if I print the queryset.query, it's doing the correct SQL statement(as in it's got where deleted=0). But the results returned via the api request still seems to ignore the flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can filter fields using lambda bundle attribute showing table name and field name.

```
tags = fields.ToManyField('django_app.api.TagsResource', attribute=lambda bundle: bundle.obj.tags.filter(tags__deleted=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow... I've been looking all day for this!  the "attribute" is exactly what I was looking for.  I almost started hacking at my models to do the filtering there out of despair.

[From the Resource Field documentation for ToManyField:](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html)

> Provides access to related data via a join table.
>
> This subclass requires Django’s ORM layer to work properly.
>
> This field also has special behavior when dealing with attribute in
>   that it can take a callable. For instance, if you need to filter the
>   reverse relation, you can do something like:

```
subjects = fields.ToManyField(SubjectResource, attribute=lambda bundle: Subject.objects.filter(notes=bundle.obj, name__startswith='Personal'))
```