# How to filter ToManyField of django-tastypie by request.user?

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I'm building an API with tastypie for a django app for data based on the user. The resources are like this:

```
class PizzaResource(ModelResource):
    toppings = fields.ToManyField(
                'project.app.api.ToppingResource', 
                'topping_set'
            )

    class Meta:
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        queryset = Pizza.objects.all()

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(users=request.user)


class ToppingResource(ModelResource):
    pizza = fields.ForeignKey(PizzaResource, 'pizza')

    class Meta:
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        queryset = Topping.objects.filter()
```

The according models are like this:

```
class Pizza(model):
    users = ManyToManyField(User)
    toppings = ManyToManyField(Topping)
    # other stuff

class Topping(Model):
    used_by = ManyToManyField(User)
    # other stuff
```

Now what I want to do is filter the `toppings` listed with `pizza` by the `Topping.used_by` field. I just found [how to filter this field by request unrelated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557790/tastypie-filtering-many-to-many-relationships).

How can I filter a relationship field of `tastypie` by request data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer by stepping through the code of tastypie. It turned out, that the model field in the definition of the `ToMany` relation (`topping_set` here) can be set to a callable.

Inside the callable you get as only parameter the `bundle` of data used to dehydrate the resulting data. Inside this `bundle` is always the request and so the `user` instance I want to use to filter.

So what I did was changing this:

```
toppings = fields.ToManyField(
    'project.app.api.ToppingResource', 
    'topping_set'
)
```

to this:

```
toppings = fields.ToManyField(
    'project.app.api.ToppingResource', 
    lambda bundle: Topping.objects.filter(
        pizza=bundle.obj, 
        used_by=bundle.request.user
    )
)
```

and that is it!

Comment: Any ways to do this but it doesn't query for all the objects? Before I was doing a prefetch_related... for example in my queryset I was doing a prefetch_related('topping_set'), and it would mean ONE query for all the objects. Now however it does a query for each object returned...