# django-tastypie - filtering on many to many relationship

Tags: django, tastypie

I have models: course and tag with an intermediate join model coursetag (for the many-to-many relationship).

In my API the TagResource shows the tags, along with the count of the number of courses. Then when the user requests (via the API) a specific tag they get a list of all the course with the specified tag. All this is working fine... however, I now need to be able to filter the courses depending on the user (whether they have user.is_staff set to True or not).

I can get this to work showing the correct count of courses in the tag list API, but I'm having problems figuring out how to filter the courses when a specific tag is chosen.

My API Resources are as follows:

```
class TagResource(ModelResource):
    count = fields.IntegerField(readonly=True)
    courses = fields.ToManyField('oppia.api.resources.CourseTagResource', 'coursetag_set', related_name='tag', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Tag.objects.filter(courses__isnull=False).distinct().order_by("name")
        resource_name = 'tag'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        fields = ['id','name']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = ReadOnlyAuthorization() 
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False
        serializer = TagJSONSerializer()

    def dehydrate_count(self,bundle):
        if bundle.request.user.is_staff:
            count = Course.objects.filter(tag__id=bundle.obj.id).count()
        else:
            count = Course.objects.filter(tag__id=bundle.obj.id, staff_only=False).count()
        return count 

class CourseResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Course.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'course'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'version', 'shortname']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = ReadOnlyAuthorization() 
        serializer = CourseJSONSerializer()
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = True

class CourseTagResource(ModelResource):
    course = fields.ToOneField('oppia.api.resources.CourseResource', 'course', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = CourseTag.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        fields = ['id','course','tag']
        include_resource_uri = False
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = ReadOnlyAuthorization()
        always_return_data = True
```

And the sample requests/responses are as follows:

For the list of tags (eg. `http://localhost/python/api/v1/tag/?username=XXXetc`), I get the expected response:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 10}, "tags": [{"count": 1, "id": 8, "name": "34343434"}, {"count": 2, "id": 2, "name": "Education"}, {"count": 1, "id": 7, "name": "Engineering"}, {"count": 1, "id": 13, "name": "Ethiopia"}, {"count": 1, "id": 10, "name": "health"}, {"count": 5, "id": 1, "name": "Healthcare"}, {"count": 1, "id": 11, "name": "phone"}, {"count": 1, "id": 12, "name": "PNC"}, {"count": 1, "id": 6, "name": "Solar"}, {"count": 1, "id": 9, "name": "test"}]}
```

However for a specific tag (eg. `http://localhost/python/api/v1/tag/13/?username=XXXetc`), I get the correct count (1 course), but wrong course listing (2 courses):

```
{"count": 1, "courses": [{"id": 2, "resource_uri": "/python/api/v1/course/2/", "shortname": "pnc", "title": {"en": "Postnatal Care"}, "url": "http://localhost/python/api/v1/course/2/download/", "version": "20131105085218"}, {"id": 30, "resource_uri": "/python/api/v1/course/30/", "shortname": "anc2", "title": {"en": "Antenatal Care v2"}, "url": "http://localhost/python/api/v1/course/30/download/", "version": "20131106162547"}], "id": 13, "name": "Ethiopia"}
```

I've attempted to use a similar approach to the one given here: [How to filter ToManyField of django-tastypie by request.user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417202/how-to-filter-tomanyfield-of-django-tastypie-by-request-user?lq=1) but I can't figure out how to apply the lambda function depending on whether the user.is_staff.

I've also attempted to put authorization limit on the CourseResource and CourseTagResource, but this doesn't seem to make any difference either.

For info I'm using tastypie 0.9.16 and Django 1.5.

Any help/pointers are much appreciated, and any advice on whether I'm taken the right approach would be helpful - I wasn't sure if I should be looking at the course models permissions instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured a way to achieve what I wanted... it's not pretty and certainly wouldn't recommend this approach, however it works for me.

I ended up removing the ToManyField in my TagResource, then overriding the API detail URI, using:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('tag_detail'), name="api_tag_detail"),
        ]

def tag_detail(self, request, **kwargs): 
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    self.throttle_check(request)

    pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
    try:
        tag = self._meta.queryset.get(pk = pk)
    except Tag.DoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound(_(u'Tag not found'))

    if request.user.is_staff:
        courses = Course.objects.filter(tag=tag, is_archived=False).order_by("title")
    else:
        courses = Course.objects.filter(tag=tag, is_archived=False,is_draft=False).order_by("title")

    course_data = []
    cr = CourseResource()
    for c in courses:
        bundle = cr.build_bundle(obj=c,request=request)
        d = cr.full_dehydrate(bundle)
        course_data.append(bundle.data)

    response = HttpResponse(content=json.dumps({'id':pk,'count':courses.count(),'courses':course_data,'name':tag.name}),content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8")
    return response
```

If anyone has any better approaches, then I'd be happy to hear...