# Django Tastypie Reference the Same ForeignKey Model More Than Once

Tags: django, tastypie

Is there a way to reference the same ForeignKey model/resource more than once in Tastypie?

Assume the models:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Interaction(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, related_name="interaction_cases")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Assume the TastyPie resources:

```
class CaseResource(ModelResource):
    type_one_interactions = fields.ManyToManyField('TypeOneInteractionFullResource', 'interaction_cases', null=True, full_list=True, full=True)
    type_two_interactions = fields.ManyToManyField('TypeTwoInteractionFullResource', 'interaction_cases', null=True, full_list=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Case.objects.all()

class TypeOneInteractionResource(ModelResource):
    case = fields.ForeignKey(Case,'case')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Interaction.objects.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(TypeOneInteractionResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(type='A')

class TypeTwoInteractionResource(ModelResource):
    case = fields.ForeignKey(Case,'case')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Interaction.objects.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(TypeTwoInteractionResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(type='B')
```

Basically I am trying to create a single resource with two reverse resources to the same model with different data. When I access the CaseResource I see both TypeOneInteractionResource and TypeTwoInteractionResource in the result, but the data is not being filtered correctly.

I assume it has something to do with the "related_name" being the same and the way TastyPie does model joining internally. Has anybody been successful doing this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `get_object_list` is not called at all when dehydrating the `ToManyField` for related resources (see https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/fields.py#L780).

Instead, you'd want to use the `dehydrate_type_one_interactions` and `dehydrate_type_two_interactions` methods on the `CaseResource`.

On the other hand, you can provide properties on the `Case` model that would return desired QuerySets and use those properties for attribute names in ManyToManyFields.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The last sentence made me look around and find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417202/how-to-filter-tomanyfield-of-django-tastypie-by-request-user and that solved my issue.